# Map RowDataCollection to DTO using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, datarow, datarowcollection

Is there a way to map a **RowDataCollection to DTO** using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)?

Here is a scenario: **DataRow to Object**

```
user.UserId = row["UserId"];
user.UserName = row["UserName"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**glbal.asax configuration**

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<DataRow, EventCompactViewModel>()
      .ConvertUsing(x => (EventCompactViewModel)AutomapperExtensions.DataRowMapper(x, typeof(EventCompactViewModel), null));
```

**Data row mapper**

```
public static object DataRowMapper(DataRow dataRow, Type type, string prefix)
{
    try
    {
        var returnObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            foreach (DataColumn key in dataRow.Table.Columns)
            {
                string columnName = key.ColumnName;
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataRow[columnName].ToString()))
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) || columnName.Length > prefix.Length)
                    {
                        String propertyNameToMatch = String.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) ? columnName : columnName.Substring(property.Name.IndexOf(prefix) + prefix.Length + 1);
                        propertyNameToMatch = propertyNameToMatch.ToPascalCase();
                        if (property.Name == propertyNameToMatch)
                        {

                            Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType;

                            object safeValue = (dataRow[columnName] == null) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(dataRow[columnName], t);

                            property.SetValue(returnObject, safeValue, null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return returnObject;
    }
    catch (MissingMethodException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: .ToPascalCase() is not found in latest AutoMapper 1.1 lib, what is the alternative?

Comment: you can use ToPascalCase from subsonic

Answer (score 0):

You could do a [custom type converter](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters).  And, if you're sure the DTO property names will exactly match the DataRow column names, you could probably do a little reflection and have a single type converter.