# Automapper DynamicMap missing

Tags: c#, automapper

I was reading in a previous question on "[How to use AutoMapper to map a DataRow to an object in a WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222313/how-to-use-automapper-to-map-a-datarow-to-an-object-in-a-wcf-service)" and I thought 'Great! That's what I'm looking for on mapping a table from MySQL!', yet after I got the Nuget package and tried to use that line of code like this:

```
List<Customer> c = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<Customer>>(dt.CreateDataReader());
```

I got this exception:

> 'Mapper' does not contain a definition for 'DynamicMap'

After checking around on the 'net about it, I found out it's been taken out. So then how does one create a List from MySQL DB Table?

Comment: Are you using AutoMapper 3.1.1?

Comment: no, it's AutoMapper 6.1.1

Comment: AutoMapper 3.1.1 will work. Otherwise see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

[DataReaderMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.DataReaderMapper/) can be used to achieve this. See https://github.com/aygjiay/AutoMapper.DataReaderMapper or https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Data for details.

Comment: Okay, I see where you're going with this, but the documentation is scant. How do I implement this with my code above? Can you give example(s)?

Comment: Is swapping to AutoMapper 3.1.1 an option?

Comment: I could consider it yes; however, my team does like to keep up with the latest packages that are out there, and if there's a way to keep it current, it would me much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The AutoMapper has many changes since the 3.1.1 version.

The below change from `DynamicMap` method to `Map` method should work.

```
List<Customer> c = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<Customer>>(dt.CreateDataReader());
```